# Convergent squence in topology

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis

Please,

I consider this topological space $(E,\tau)$ where $\tau=\{G\subset E, ~\text{card}~ (E\setminus G)~\text{countable}\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$

How to prove that a sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent in $(E,\tau)$ if and only if $(x_n)$ is stable ??

> We say that $(x_n)$ is stable if $\exists~ n_0$ such that $n\geq n_0,
>  x_n= a $

Please help me

thank you

Comment: I think "stable" is not standard terminology (not necessarily unusual, but it need not be known by everybody). Often, one says "eventually constant" - if "stable" means what I think it means. To make sure, add the definition/an explanation of the term "stable" to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m going to assume that by *stable sequence* you mean a sequence that is eventually constant: there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n=x_m$ for all $n\ge m$. I expect that you can prove that such a sequence converges in any space.

Now suppose that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence in $E$ that converges to $x$.

HINT: Let $A=\{x_n:x_n\ne x\}$. What can you say about the set $X\setminus A$?

Comment: $X\setminus A$ is finite and coutable ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: No, $A$ is countable. So $X\setminus A$ is ... ?

Comment: i don't know i don't see

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Sorry: that should have been $E\setminus A$. Look at the definition of $\tau$. The complement of a countable set is ... ?

Comment: uncountable ! !!!!

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Yes, it’s uncountable, but that’s not important. **Look at the definition of** $\tau$. How does $E\setminus A$ relate to that?

Comment: it's related to it's cardinal, it must be countable

Comment: @Vrouvrou recall the definition of $\tau$!

Comment: @Vrouvrou: You’ve just contradicted yourself. We agreed a moment ago that $E\setminus A$ is **uncountable**. But forget the cardinality of $E\setminus A$: it’s not important. What kind of sets are open in $E$?

Comment: the element of $\tau$ are subsets $G$ from $E$ such that $\text{card}~( E\ G)$ is countable

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Right. And $E\setminus(E\setminus A)=A$, is countable, so $E\setminus A$ is ... ?

Comment: then $E\setminus A$ is an open !

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Yes! And $x\in E\setminus A$, so $E\setminus A$ is an open nbhd of $x$. Now use the definition of convergence of a sequence to show that the sequence must be stable at $x$.

Comment: $x_n$ converge to x then there exist $n_0$ such that $n\geq n_0, x_n\in V_x=E\setminus A$ it means that from $n_0$ $x_n=x $ it means that $x_n$ is constant ! right ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Yes, that’s exactly right.

Comment: for the invers implication we must prove that the limit is unique or it is not important, we just need that it convege an because it is stable we have that it converge to x ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Yes, you need only prove that if it’s stable at $x$, then it converges to $x$. You don’t need to prove that the limit is unique; it might not be, in fact.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott and we can find easely an other limit ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: In that particular space the limit is unique. I just meant that in some spaces a stable sequence can have more than one limit.

Comment: please juste why here the limit is unique ? thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Suppose that the sequence is stable at $x$. Let $y\in E\setminus\{x\}$. Then $E\setminus\{x\}$ is an open nbhd of $y$ that contains only finitely many terms of the sequence, so the sequence does not converge to $y$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott please from where we get the idea to use the set $A$ ? we suppose that $x_n$ is not constante ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: You want to show that the sequence is eventually constant, and since it converges to $x$, that means that you want to show that it’s equal to $x$ from some point on. That happens if and only if it has only finitely many terms that are *not* $x$, so it’s natural to look at the set of those terms. That set is $A$. Then we notice that $A$ is certainly countable, so $E\setminus A$ is a nbhd of $x$, and the rest of the argument falls into place very easily.